# What to do when ctrl+alt+m in flutter doesnt work for extracting methods in android studio

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, cross-platform

Basically my shortcut keys are not working and I ve checked in settings too

I went to settings in keymaps and all was okay there but still I changed the settings and tried it with other settings and then tried it after resetting it  but the result was same every time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.